# Not able to send advanced Adaptive card in Search message extension

Tags: botframework, chatbot, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I tried sending a simple adaptive card and I was able to send successfully in my Search Message Extension. Then I tried the below adaptive card which is more advanced and used more controls/elements and I was not able to send it in my chat. Is there any list of controls/elements which does not work in Search Message extension.
I am having the below error while trying different adaptive cards to send in chat.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'action' of null
at e.tryMatchToEnumedStringsForKnownPanleActionProperties (https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/hashed/3.2-app.min-54a576c.js:1:2193665)
at e.sendPanelAction (https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/hashed/3.2-app.min-54a576c.js:1:2191074)
at https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/hashed/3.2-app.min-54a576c.js:1:951108
at f (https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/hashed/0.2-angular-jquery.min-eee9041.js:127:115)
at https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/hashed/0.2-angular-jquery.min-eee9041.js:127:345
at m.$eval (https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/hashed/0.2-angular-jquery.min-eee9041.js:142:180)
at m.$digest (https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/hashed/0.2-angular-jquery.min-eee9041.js:139:290)
at m.v.$digest (https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/hashed/3.2-app.min-54a576c.js:1:5166871)
at https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/hashed/0.2-angular-jquery.min-eee9041.js:142:267
at e (https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/hashed/0.2-angular-jquery.min-eee9041.js:41:350) undefined
statics.teams.cdn.office.net/hashed/0.2-angular-jquery.min-eee9041.js:114
{statusCode: 500, headers: {…}, errorMessage: 'Invoke failed due to internal error', errorCode: 0, errorSubCode: undefined, …} undefined
2021-09-08T10:02:22.859Z InputExtensionService: Input extension invoke command failed
```

below is the code for adaptive card:

```js
    import { IEntity } from '../model/IEntity';
    import { Attachment, CardFactory } from "botbuilder";
    
    export class ContactResultCard {
    
    public static getCard(contact: IEntity): Attachment {
        let url = `https://pbs.twimg.com/docs/MenuPortal.aspx?GoPage=CRMAccountCard.aspx?AccountID='${contact.ID}'&_Division_='${contact.Division}'`;
        const card =  CardFactory.adaptiveCard(
            {
                "type": "AdaptiveCard",
                "body": [
                    {
                        "type": "ColumnSet",
                        "columns": [
                            {
                                "type": "Column",
                                "width": "stretch",
                                "items": [
                                    {
                                        "type": "ColumnSet",
                                        "columns": [
                                            {
                                                "type": "Column",
                                                "items": [
                                                    {
                                                        "type": "Image",
                                                        "url": "https://iconape.com/wp-content/files/hd/32658/svg/test-dao.svg",
                                                        "size": "Small",
                                                        "width": "20px",
                                                        "height": "20px",
                                                        "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
                                                        "spacing": "Small"
                                                    }
                                                ],
                                                "style": "default",
                                                "width": 12
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "type": "Column",
                                                "items": [
                                                    {
                                                        "type": "TextBlock",
                                                        "size": "Large",
                                                        "weight": "Bolder",
                                                        "text": contact.Title,
                                                        "height": "stretch"
                                                    }
                                                ],
                                                "width": 70,
                                                "height": "stretch",
                                                "style": "default"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "type": "Column",
                                                "minHeight": "0px",
                                                "style": "default",
                                                "backgroundImage": {
                                                    "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
                                                    "url": "https://i.postimg.cc/7LHgLjp6/background-Teams.jpg",
                                                    "fillMode": "RepeatHorizontally"
                                                },
                                                "height": "stretch",
                                                "width": 30,
                                                "items": [
                                                    {
                                                        "type": "TextBlock",
                                                        "text": contact.EntityType,
                                                        "weight": "Bolder",
                                                        "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
                                                        "wrap": true,
                                                        "height": "stretch",
                                                        "size": "Small"
                                                    }
                                                ],
                                                "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
                                                "spacing": "Small"
                                            }
                                        ],
                                        "height": "stretch"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "style": "default"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "ColumnSet",
                        "columns": [
                            {
                                "type": "Column",
                                "items": [
                                    {
                                        "type": "Container",
                                        "items": [
                                            {
                                                "type": "ColumnSet",
                                                "columns": [
                                                    {
                                                        "type": "Column",
                                                        "width": 75,
                                                        "items": [
                                                            {
                                                                "type": "TextBlock",
                                                                "weight": "Bolder",
                                                                "text": contact.AccountContact,
                                                                "size": "Large",
                                                                "wrap": true
                                                            },
                                                            {
                                                                "type": "TextBlock",
                                                                "spacing": "None",
                                                                "text": contact.JobTitleDescription,
                                                                "isSubtle": true,
                                                                "wrap": true
                                                            },
                                                            {
                                                                "type": "Container",
                                                                "items": [
                                                                    {
                                                                        "type": "TextBlock",
                                                                        "text": contact.Division,
                                                                        "wrap": true
                                                                    }
                                                                ]
                                                            },
                                                            {
                                                                "type": "ColumnSet",
                                                                "columns": [
                                                                    {
                                                                        "type": "Column",
                                                                        "width": 10,
                                                                        "items": [
                                                                            {
                                                                                "type": "TextBlock",
                                                                                "text": "M:",
                                                                                "wrap": true,
                                                                                "weight": "Bolder",
                                                                                "size": "Small"
                                                                            }
                                                                        ]
                                                                    },
                                                                    {
                                                                        "type": "Column",
                                                                        "width": 90,
                                                                        "items": [
                                                                            {
                                                                                "type": "TextBlock",
                                                                                "text": contact.Phone,
                                                                                "color": "Accent",
                                                                                "size": "Small",
                                                                                "wrap": true
                                                                            }
                                                                        ]
                                                                    }
                                                                ]
                                                            },
                                                            {
                                                                "type": "ColumnSet",
                                                                "columns": [
                                                                    {
                                                                        "type": "Column",
                                                                        "width": 10,
                                                                        "items": [
                                                                            {
                                                                                "type": "TextBlock",
                                                                                "text": "T:",
                                                                                "wrap": true,
                                                                                "weight": "Bolder",
                                                                                "size": "Small"
                                                                            }
                                                                        ]
                                                                    },
                                                                    {
                                                                        "type": "Column",
                                                                        "width": 90,
                                                                        "items": [
                                                                            {
                                                                                "type": "TextBlock",
                                                                                "text": contact.Mobile,
                                                                                "color": "Accent",
                                                                                "size": "Small",
                                                                                "wrap": true
                                                                            }
                                                                        ]
                                                                    }
                                                                ]
                                                            },
                                                            {
                                                                "type": "ColumnSet",
                                                                "columns": [
                                                                    {
                                                                        "type": "Column",
                                                                        "width": 10,
                                                                        "items": [
                                                                            {
                                                                                "type": "TextBlock",
                                                                                "text": "E:",
                                                                                "wrap": true,
                                                                                "weight": "Bolder",
                                                                                "size": "Small"
                                                                            }
                                                                        ]
                                                                    },
                                                                    {
                                                                        "type": "Column",
                                                                        "width": 90,
                                                                        "items": [
                                                                            {
                                                                                "type": "TextBlock",
                                                                                "text": contact.Email,
                                                                                "color": "Accent",
                                                                                "size": "Small",
                                                                                "wrap": true
                                                                            }
                                                                        ]
                                                                    }
                                                                ]
                                                            }
                                                        ]
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        "type": "Column",
                                                        "width": 20,
                                                        "items": [
                                                            {
                                                                "type": "Image",
                                                                "url": "https://i.postimg.cc/XJwDktgd/placeholder-contact.png",
                                                                "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
                                                                "size": "Medium",
                                                                "width": "55px"
                                                            }
                                                        ]
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ],
                                "width": "stretch"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "ColumnSet",
                        "columns": [
                            {
                                "type": "Column",
                                "width": 70
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "Column",
                                "width": 30,
                                "items": [
                                    {
                                        "type": "TextBlock",
                                        "text": "Open in Test",
                                        "wrap": true,
                                        "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
                                        "color": "Accent",
                                        "weight": "Bolder",
                                        "size": "Small"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "selectAction": {
                                    "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
                                    "url": url
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
                "version": "1.3"
            }
        );
    
        return card;
    }
    }
```

This is how I am sending an adaptive card:

```js
    public async handleTeamsMessagingExtensionSelectItem(
    context: TurnContext,
    obj: any
    ): Promise {
    const item = this.response.find(e => e.ID == obj.name);
    const card = TestCardFactory.getCard(item);
    return {
    composeExtension: {
    type: "result",
    attachmentLayout: "list",
    attachments: [{preview: CardFactory.heroCard("title", "Test"),
    ...card}],
    },
    };
    }
```

Comment: You can debug the card with sending your card data in smaller parts and check which part is not working.
This way you can get to know the exact issue in your card.

Also please compare your simple card contents with Advance card and you can easily identify which part of card is failing.

Comment: Thanks a lot chetan, I am able to figure out the culprits. Below are the elements which were causing issues: "backgroundImage" and column with no Text  for eg: {
                            "type": "Column",
                            "width": 70
                        },

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot chetan, I am able to figure out the culprits. Below are the elements which were causing issues:

1. "backgroundImage"
2. column with no Text  for eg: {
   "type": "Column",
   "width": 70
   },